# Two environment variables with the same name

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I tried adding an 'Environment variable' with the name "PATH" but I found another entry with the same name.
can I change the old one to a different name?
I tried openning "GPAC" folder, but didn't understand much and didn't know what to change in the configurations file

[image: Duplicate Environment variables]

Comment: yeah, you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do not remove or rename the `PATH` variable!**

Instead, just edit the existing `PATH` variable, add a delimiter (which is `;` in Windows) and  then add your new path.

Would result in something like:

```
C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\GPAC
```

Why you shouldn't delete it:

[Wikipedia: PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

This may result in a broken system (I've never tried it), but you won't be able to just run `cmd` anymore, you'll have to type `C:\Windows\cmd.exe` because Windows won't know where to look for executables without the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple path values under the PATH variable separate your values with a semi-colon.

Comment: To be clear, this is only true for certain variables. For instance adding another path to the TEMP variable would just break things.

Comment: To be clear he said "PATH".  So what's your point?

Comment: My point is that your answer implies that you can do this for any variable.

Comment: There I fixed it for you. The other answer is more comprehensive though regardless.

Comment: thank you.  I will try to be more thorough in the future.

Comment: No biggie. It's just that the goal of the stack exchange sites is to provide ideally the one best answer for each question.